# How to pass information from one component to nested children components in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I have a component `xyz-comp` which is used inside a `master-comp`. And there is another component `abc-comp` which is used inside the `xyz-comp` as part of its `ng-content`.

**Master-Comp:**

```
<xyz-comp (outX)="draw($event)">
    <abc-comp class="breaker" [data]="incomingLabel">
    </abc-comp>
</xyz-comp>
```

**xyz-comp:**

```
<div class="searcher">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

**xyz-comp.ts:**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "xyz-comp",
    templateUrl: "./xyz.html"
})
export class Xyz {

    @Output() outX = new EventEmitter(false);

    label: string;

    constructor(private _ref: ElementRef) {
        this._getlabel();
    }

    private _getlabel() {
        this.label = someFunc();
        this.outX.emit(this.label);
    }
}
```

**Master-comp.ts:**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "master-comp",
    templateUrl: "./master.html"
})
export class Master {

    incomingLabel: string;

    constructor(private _ref: ElementRef) {

    }

    draw(evt: string) { // This function is not getting called.
        console.log(evt); 
        this.incomingLabel = evt;
    }
}
```

Inside the Master-comp.ts, the method `draw()` which should be triggered as soon as the `outX` output event is emitted. But the `draw()` method is not getting invoked.

Furthermore, I would like to use that `incomingLabel` value in the abc-comp as follows:

**abc-comp.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "abc-comp",
    templateUrl: "./abc.html"
})
export class Abc {

    @Input() data: string;

    constructor(private _ref: ElementRef) {

    }

}
```

**abc-comp:**

```
<div class="draw-container">
   <span [attr.id]="data"></span>
 </div>
```

Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: The `draw()` is not getting called after the `outX` event is emitted. When I debug it by putting a breakpoint in the  `_getlabel()`, it does go in there but the breakpoint in the `draw()` never gets triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `this._getlabel();` in `ngOnInit()` or `ngAfterViewInit()`. The constructor is called even before `ngOnInit`. Neither the component is created nor the view has been created by then so though the method in the constructor will be called, the `emit` will have no effect